# Imagemagick: Convert to fixed height, proportional width

Tags: imagemagick, image

Using Imagemagick, I'd like to `convert` a batch of PNGs to a fixed height of 1080px and a *proportional width*. With *proportional* I mean this: If the original Image is scaled down 16.8% to 1080px, the width also needs to be scaled down by 16.8%.

Any way of using convert without having to calculate the exact geometry before (using `identify` and some bash calculation shenanigans) ?

Comment: fixed width: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7200909/imagemagick-convert-to-fixed-width-proportional-height

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is one additional example. give it some values to the resize parameters and it'll automatically resize your image. Plus you can chose other parameters (gravity center or crop etc.).

```
  convert image_example: \
          -resize x160 -resize '160x<'   -resize 50% \
          -gravity center  -crop 80x80+0+0 +repage  image_example.jpg
```

Cheers

Answer (score 82):

Try this:

```
convert -resize x1080 {from_path} {to_path}
```

Answer (score 7):

[Image geometry](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php#geometry) is an option described to use with `-resize`

```
xheight Height given, width automagically selected to preserve aspect ratio.
```

So you only have to specify the height