# Imagemagick: Convert to fixed width, proportional height

Tags: imagemagick

Using the imagemagick convert command, how can I resize an image to a fixed width and proportional height e.g. using the -resize or the -thumbnail option?

Answer (score 158, accepted):

Use `-resize 100x` to resize images to 100 pixels in width while maintaining the height's aspect ratio.

Read the fine [ImageMagick manual](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/resize/) for details.

Comment: imagemagick comes with `mogrify` which will alter original image. I found it easiser to copy the images into a new folder then run `mogrify -resize 512x *.jpg`

Comment: mkdir will complain if the directory already exists. To avoid this, add the -p flag "no error if existing" to mkdir. `mkdir -p thumbnails` explained in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4906579/how-to-use-bash-to-create-a-folder-if-it-doesnt-already-exist

Comment: How do you resize to specified width, but original height?

Answer (score 98):

Imagemagick geometry: 'width'x'height'
If you leave one part empty, this means resize proportional.

Examples:

```
100x200       # width = 100, height = 200
300x          # width = 300, height = proportional
x300          # width = proportional, height = 300
```

Comment: `100x200` will create an image with theses dimensions. The original picture will keep its ratio W/H. `100x200\!` will also create an image with theses dimensions, but image inside will be deformed to stick the new dimensions.

Comment: @MTranchant & chrise : AFAICS, `-geometry 100x200` behaves as `min(100x, x200)` (ImageMagick 6.9.2.7, Fedora 23).

Answer (score 0):

For nubie's like me...
Windows: Powershell: for Facebook Photos for example:

Right click windows '*Start*', select '*Terminal*'

C: cd to directory that you require to do conversion from:
ie: *cd Users/OneDrive/Pictures*

C: *mkdir FBName* ;creates sub-directory '*makedir ./FBName'* does the same.

C: *magick name.jpg -resize 2048 ./FBName/newname.jpg*

; Will resize 'name.jpg' with a max size of 2048 (long edge, portrait or landscape) into the subdirectory FBName that you created previously. Linux would replace 'magick' with 'convert'